# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ........................... . (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: json, azure, security, cors, azure-blob-storage

I have a simple html file saved in my desktop. This html file needs to send the link to a json file(stored in azure blob) to the app included in this webpage.

**Script part of the webpage**

```
<script>
var zbc = "https://blobtempdemo.blob.core.windows.net/path/to_required_file.json";
require(['scripts/SampleApp/App'], function(App)
{
App.start(abc);
});
```

The json file is stored in microsoft azure blob. When i run the webpage in Mozilla Firefox, it gives a warning saying

**Warning**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blobtempdemo.blob.core.windows.net/path/to_required_file.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The app/ web page works perfectly when all the files are saved in my desktop.
When i paste the url in the firefox, it can get the file and ask me if i want to download it. But it does not work when the file is in the blob and i open this webpage.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Just allow CORS from all the domains (just to test) in the target storage account. That should do it. Use `*` as the value for allowed domains.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services